# Form queryset filter not working, cleaned_data not matching "CHOICES=..."

Tags: python, django, forms, filter, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a form that allows end-users to filter transaction data. I have a filter for "payment method".

```
For Example: credit card, cash, check etc.
```

For some reason, my results do not filter (nothing shows up). I noticed that the form changes my filters value from the choices available.

```
For Example: the "cash" choice becomes [u'cash'].
```

If I enter the choice option directly in my filter, it works.

```
For Example: Transactions.objects.filter(payment_method__exact="cash")
```

Not sure if this has anything to do with it... How can I get my filter to work?

MODELS:

```
class QueryForm(forms.Form):
    payment_method = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=PAYMENT_TYPE)
```

VIEW:

```
def findtransation(request):
    qf = QueryForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        qf = QueryForm(request.POST)
        if qf.is_valid():
            p = qf.cleaned_data['payment_method']
            results = Transactions.objects.filter(payment_method__exact=p)
            return render_to_response('testdb/results.html', {'results': results, 'query_form': qf,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('testdb/results.html', {'query_form': qf,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've used a MultipleChoiceField because you do actually want to be able to select multiple items - for example you want to search for transactions whose payment method is *either* cash or card - you can keep the field as it is, but change the filter to use `__in` instead of `__exact`:

```
results = Transactions.objects.filter(payment_method__in=p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `payment_method` field in your `QueryForm` to a plain `ChoiceField`:

```
class QueryForm(forms.Form):
    payment_method = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PAYMENT_TYPE)
```

A `forms.MultipleChoiceField` returns a list of strings. You didn't show your `Transactions` model, but its `payment_method` field is probably a `CharField`. So I think what is happening is you're trying to filter on the `CharField` in your `Transaction` model using the list that is returned from `QueryForm.MultipleChoiceField`. (It works fine when you hard-code the string "cash")

Comment: Awesome it works, but now I'm forced to select only one option. How do I get the form to select for multiple options?

Comment: Is it possible to create a transaction with more than one payment method? i.e., pay partly with a credit card, and partly with cash? Since that's not likely, Daniel Roseman's answer explains how to do what you probably need.